# Implementing arrays in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database

Is there any provision for creating arrays (variable length would be preferable) in MySQL . I need to create 2-3 lists for each user and update/append/delete items from the lists . How do I implement them? . Creating tables for each user will lead to a total mess in my opinion, but anyway I'm new to MySQL so please help me out . Thanks

EDIT:The lists will be one dimensional and contain the ids of other users.

Comment: In order to help, you need to describe your "lists" in more detail, describe the data and its relation to "user". Are the 2-3 "lists" related in any way?

Comment: are the lists just 1 dimension?

Comment: It will not really help you but Firebird and PostgreSQL support array ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better if you told us what you are trying to do, not how you are trying to achieve it. Anyway, you can solve it using three tables `List1`, `List2` and `List3` with columns `USER_ID`, `YOUR_VALUE`.
You query the list for the specified user using this query:

```
SELECT YOUR_VALUE FROM List1 WHERE USER_ID=<user id>
```

Updating values:

```
UPDATE List1 SET YOUR_VALUE=<value> WHERE USER_ID=<user_id>
```

Deleting all values for a specified user:

```
DELETE FROM List1 WHERE USER_ID=<user_id>
```

Delete some values (depending on a condition) for a given user:

```
DELETE FROM List1 WHERE USER_ID=<user_id> AND YOUR_VALUE=<value>
```

Comment: Tables are, after all, lists.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not possible to create arrays in mysql as of now. but however, you can maintain xml in mysql(required 5.1+)

```
check below link for same
```

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html